# Generating reporty-ng TestNG reports with Ant fails

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant, testng

In a command prompt, when I run the test cases with Reporty-**testng-xslt**, the build is successful and testng.xml is not triggered.

When I click on the index.html, nothing is displayed.

But when I run the testng xml alone with the main class, it runs well. When I run with the testng-xslt, it does not work.

### Command Prompt

```
C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree>ant -buildfile reporty-ng-report.xml

Buildfile: C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\reporty-ng-report.xml

reporty-ng-report:
[delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\reporty-ng
[mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\reporty-ng
[xslt] Processing C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\lib\testng.xml to C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\reporty-ng\index.html
[xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\Users\workspace\LoggerThree\resources\testng-results.xsl

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

### Ant script

```xml
<project name="Reporty-ng Report" default="reporty-ng-report" basedir=".">
    <!-- Sets the property variables to point to respective directories -->
    <property name="xslt-report-dir" value="${basedir}/reporty-ng/" />
    <property name="report-dir" value="${basedir}/html-report" />
    <property name="lib-dir" value="${basedir}/lib" />

    <path id="test.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib-dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="reporty-ng-report">
        <delete dir="${xslt-report-dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${xslt-report-dir}" />
        <xslt in="${basedir}/lib/testng.xml"
            style="${basedir}/resources/testng-results.xsl"
            out="${basedir}/reporty-ng/index.html" processor="SaxonLiaison"
        >
            <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir"
                expression="${xslt-report-dir}" />
            <param name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks" expression="true" />
            <param name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter" 
                expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" />
            <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
            <classpath refid="test.classpath" />
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```

### TestNG XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Automationsuite">
  <test name="demoTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="main.NewTest" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

### Java code

```java
 public class NewTest {
   @Test
   public void testMethodOne() {
     Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }

   @Test
   public void testMethodTwo() {
     Assert.assertTrue(false);
   }

   @Test(dependsOnMethods={"testMethodTwo"})
   public void testMethodThree() {
     Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

Guide me to reach out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the below link and executed the code. It works good.

[TestNG-XSLT](http://learn-automation.com/generate-xslt-report-in-selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

In build.xml file you specified

```
 <xslt in="${basedir}/lib/testng.xml"
```

I am expecting generally we will have testng.xml file in base directory and all jars in lib folder. So did you placed testng.xml file also in lib folder?

This [link](http://blog.varunin.com/2010/05/generating-selenium-reports-using.html) has some information on generating xslt reports like you tried.

Thank You,
Murali G

Comment: Yes I placed the build.xml file in the lib folder only.